# How to generate the CSV and PDF selecting two dates json value in Drupal7

Tags: php, arrays, json, drupal-7

```
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename=csvfile.csv');
 // code indentation    
 $fp = fopen('php://transactions', 'w')
 foreach ($result->response as $transaction) {
     fputcsv($fp, $transaction);
 }
 fclose($fp);
 drupal_exit();
```

The (result->response as transaction) contains all the data, with that only i arrange in table format to view for the customer. This same data i am selecting (from and to->date result) to be download in CSV.

**Print of transaction:**
In stdClassObject([card]=>1234,[fromdate]=>4/1/2016,[amount]=>5000)

Suggestion Needed.

Comment: what errors are you getting.

Comment: I am getting the Empty CSV file

Comment: have you tried to print $transaction after removing the drupal_add_http_header() functions. I am sure that the $transaction / $result is empty.

Comment: I Generated output     echo implode(PHP_EOL , $resp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
fputcsv($fp, $transaction);
```

Use

```
fputcsv($fp, array($transaction->card, $transaction->fromdate, $transaction->amount));
```

for formatting the numbers you can use as below:

```
$number = (float) str_replace( ',', '', '5,000.00');
echo number_format($number, '2','.', '');
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for suggestions

Comment: I need a clarification if amount comes with 5,000 i should display with 5000 but on comma seperated values it throws after comma value to another cell.

Comment: on use number_format(5,000.00, 2, '.', ''); displays only output: 5000 but i like to display as 5000.00